# I want to find the minumum point of any discrete function by using gradient descent method

Tags: optimization, gradient

I want to find the minimum point of any discrete function by using gradient descent method but I don't know how can I evaluate derivative of the function for a specific point. For example

```
function = [100 81 64 49 36 25 16 9 4 1 0 1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100]
derivative = [ -19 -17 -15 -13 -11 -9 -7 -5 -3 -1 1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19]
```

for gradient descent algorithm

```
x_next = x_now - alfa * derivative(x_now)
```

but how can I evaluate `derivative(x_now)`? I hope you will understand what I mean thanks

Comment: Maybe http://math.stackexchange.com is more suited

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as I understand it it's a math question

Comment: I would suggest [*computational science*](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you know the x values corresponding to your discrete function values, e.g.,

```
x = [-5 -4 -3 -2 ... ],
function = [100 81 64 49 36 ... ],
derivative = [-19 -17 -15 -13 ...],
```

the derivative in the gradient descent method can taken as constant over each interval [x_(i), x_(i+1)). I.e., in pseudocode

```
derivative(x_now) = derivative(x_i), where x_(i) <= x_now < x_(i+1).
```

As and example, using the x values above:

```
derivative(-3.5) = -15
```